# Photoshop dialog controls keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: javascript, dialog, keyboard, photoshop, shortcut

I can't seem to get any keyboard shortcuts to work with my Photoshop dialog. This is the control that I've tried adding one to:

```
 dlg.btnPnl.General = dlg.btnPnl.add('button', [20,25,300,45], 'Table Shots', {name:'ok'}, ); dlg.btnPnl.General.shortcutKey = "1";
```

The whole script runs fine; dialog pops up, but nothing happens when I press 1. I've used [this guide](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html) as a reference, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your preferences by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Alt at the same time while launching the app.